# Recurrence induction

Tags: induction, recursion

below is $a_n$

\begin{cases} 
      0 & n = 0 \\
      9 & n = 1 \\
      7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-1} + 5^n & n > 1 
 \end{cases}

$S(n): \forall n \in \mathbb N, a_n \leq 3 \cdot7^n -d\cdot5^n$

Basis:

for $n = 0$

$a_n = 1 \leq 3 - d = 3 \cdot 7^0-d\cdot5^0 = 3 \cdot7^n -d\cdot5^n$ [def of $S(0)$], holds

Therefore we need $1 \leq 3 -d$

for $n=1$

$a_n = 9 \leq 27 - 5d = 3 \cdot 7^1-d\cdot5^1 = 3 \cdot7^n -d\cdot5^n$ [def of $S(1)$], holds

Therefore we need $9 \leq 27 - 5d$

Inductive step: let $n > 1$

Suppose $a_j \leq 3 \cdot 7^j - 5^j\cdot d$, whenever $0 \leq j < n$ [I.H]

WTP: $a_n \leq 3 \cdot 7^n - 5^n d$

$a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-1} + 5^n$ [def of $a_n$; $n > 1]$

$\leq 7(3 \cdot 7^{n-2} - 5^{n-2}d) + 6(3 \cdot 7^{n-1} - 5^{n-1}d) + 5^n$ [I.H]

$= 3\cdot7^{n-1} - 7 \cdot 5^{n-2}d + 18 \cdot 7^{n-1} - 6 \cdot 5^{n-1}d + 5^n$ [expanded]

$= 7^{n-1} (3 + 18) - 5^{n-2}(37d + 25)$ [common factor]

$= 7^{n-1}(21) - 5^{n-2}(37d + 25)$

I'm confused on how to achieve the WTP(what to prove) and find sufficient d. The original question was $S(n): \forall n \in \mathbb N, a_n \leq 3 \cdot7^n$ but the $5^n$ was impossible to work around

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You might find $37d+25 \ge 25d$ for positive $d$ helpful.

Comment: `The original question was ...` You are having a problem with that, yet you are trying to prove a *stronger* inequality? For a different approach (without induction), let $a_n=5^n b_n\,$, then you get $25 b_n = 30 b_{n-1}+ 7 b_{n-2} + 1$ which is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients.

Comment: WTP: $a_n≤3⋅7^{n}−5^{n}d$ is what im tryna get at, and the original question is a harder proof cus you can't work it out through algebra?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that $a_n-6a_{n-1}-7a_{n-2}=5^n$ has characteristic equation $(x-7)(x+1)$ and nonhomogeneous part $5^n$ so $a_n=c_1\cdot 7^n+c_2\cdot (-1)^n+c_3\cdot 5^n$ for some constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ which depend on the values of $a_0$ and $a_1$.  You can take what I say as magic for now until you learn the general method for solving for closed forms of linear recurrences later and just use the result and prove that $a_n$ is equal to exactly what you find, proving the equality with induction.  The inequality that you are after will follow immediately.